# An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am passing a value from controller to View using ViewBag and storing it in a variable. Then from the same view I am sending the value back to Controller stored in the variable. Earlier it used to work but recently it started giving me below error.

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'nServiceId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult SaveRequest(Int32, BussinessObjects.class1,
>   System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection)'. An optional parameter must be a
>   reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional
>   parameter.

My code is as below:

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult EnterData(int nServiceId)
{
    ViewBag.ServiceId = nServiceId;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveRequest(int nServiceId, GetQuoteInfo viewModel, FormCollection fCollection)
{

}
```

**View:**

```
@{int nServiceId = ViewBag.ServiceId;}
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveRequest",
    "MyController",
    FormMethod.Post,
    new
    {
        name = "EnterData",
        id = "EnterData",
        nServiceId = nServiceId
    }))
```

Comment: What does the GetQuoteInfo view model look like? At first glance it looks like you may have an nServiceID on the viewModel that is being set, whereby the nServiceID never gets passed in.

Comment: How do you call EnterData action result?

Comment: @MartinNoreke GetQuoteInfo is just simple class containing Strings. And I verified during debug and from view-source, nServiceID is being set correctly.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan, Its called from another controller passing the value. How does it matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing a value for `nServiceId` to the controller. You are using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470539(v=vs.118).aspx) of `Html.BeginForm()` where the last parameter `(new { name = "EnterData", id = "EnterData", nServiceId = nServiceId }`) is adding `nServiceId  = "nServiceId"` as a html attribute, not a route value (inspect the html it generates).

You need to use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505151(v=vs.118).aspx) where the usage is

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveRequest", "MyController", new { nServiceId = nServiceId }, FormMethod.Post, new { name = "EnterData", id = "EnterData" }))
```

or `new { nServiceId = ViewBag.ServiceId }`